# enviar una imagen mediante ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

```js
function objetoAjax() {
  var xmlhttp = false;

  try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }

  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

  return xmlhttp;
}

var xhttp = objetoAjax();

function enviar(form) {
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = "no enviado";
        }
    }

    xhttp.open("POST","subir.php", true);
    xhttp.send(new FormData(form));
}
```

Comment: puedes mostrar tu codigo html y php

Comment: si claro ahorita lo muestro

Comment: pudiste probar la respuesta anterior ?

Comment: si pero igual me dio el mismo error, que no se recibe ningun archivo

Answer (score 0):

Podrías resumir tu código con jquery, esto enviaría tu form por post, a la url indicada

```
$("#MyForm").submit(function(e) {
    var url = "subir.php";
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#MyForm").serialize(),
           success: function(data)
           {
                    document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = data;
           },
           error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                   document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = "no enviado";
           }
         });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es el codigo HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>index</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="respuesta">
            hola mundo
        </div>

        <form id="form" action="javascript: enviar(this)">
            <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo">
            <input type="submit" value="enviar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

este es el codigo PHP

```html
<?php
    $nombre_temporal = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

    echo $nombre;
    $destino = "archivos/" . $nombre;
    move_uploaded_file($nombre_temporal, $destino);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:
tienes el elemento HTML

```
<input id="foto" class="form-control" name="file1" type="file" />
```

Aqui las funciones JS, la función que sube el archivo es "uploadFile"

```
function _(el){
                return document.getElementById(el);
            }
            function uploadFile(){
                var file = _("file1").files[0];
                var formdata = new FormData();
                formdata.append("file1", file);
                formdata.append("id_curso", $("#id_curso").val());
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
                ajax.open("POST", "{LA_RUTA}");
                ajax.send(formdata);
            }
            function progressHandler(event){
                _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
                var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
                _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
            }
            function completeHandler(event){
                var obj = JSON.parse(event.target.response);
                if(obj.Result == "OK"){
                    //"Realizado Correctamente."
                }else{
                    
                }
                
                _("progressBar").value = 0;
            }
            function errorHandler(event){
                _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
            }
            function abortHandler(event){
                _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
            }
```

El codigo PHP

```
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"];
    $fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"];
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"];
    if (!$fileTmpLoc) {
        //exit();
    }
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "{LA_RUTA_DONDE_GUARDA}")
```